# auto align class attributes in html / vue template

Tags: html, vue.js, visual-studio-code

is there any extension in vscode that can help us to auto-align the html  / vue template like this？

thanks for your help.

```
<div class = "col flex mg-10" v-model:id="id" > </div>
    

<div
   class = "
     col 
     flex 
     mg-10"  
   v-model:id="id"
 >
 </div>
```

Comment: It's not conventional to format attribute values this way, "col flex mg-10" and "
     col 
     flex 
     mg-10"  are two different strings . The rest of formatting is handled by Prettier

Comment: You could have a super small width for your Prettier configuration.